# How to clear (a separator color) in particular section in tableview (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Currently i am working in iPhone application, using tableview to develop the tables and its style like grouped, No.of section like 2, then the 1st section has separator color like  lightgray color and the 2nd section has separator color like clearColor.
but when i scrolled the table view, sometimes 2nd section active at the time 1st section also clear a separator color, How to fix this? Please any one help me

Thanks in Advance

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

       if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) 
        {
            studentUpdateTable.separatorColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
       else if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0)
       {
            studentUpdateTable.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
       }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

you can just set to to None instead of trying to set it to clearColor

Comment: But this also get same result.

Answer (score 2):

This did works

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
```

Added a custom UIView (newly allocated UIView) as the cell's background view.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done from the Interface builder itself.. in the ATTRIBUTES INSPECTOR for the table view, u can select the separator style... no coding required whatsoever...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your issue is you are allocating the cell every time when you scroll, since tableView reuses the cell, no need to allocate it every time. if the cell is nil, then only allocate it.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) 
    {   
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
      cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

   if (indexPath.section == 0) 
   {
        studentUpdateTable.separatorColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   }
   else if(indexPath.section == 1)
   {
        studentUpdateTable.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   }
}
```

Comment: Just a comment: if you use "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier", you don't have to check if the cell is nil and initialize a cell manually. This is done for you automatically by the system (that's the point of dequeuing cells)